# How to manually map a virtual address to a page in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), and i am trying to do a test of mapping kernel memory.

This test does similar things as `vmalloc()` does. It gets a virtual memory address and a free page, then it needs to map the virtual memory address to the page or the physical address.

I think I can use kernel functions of `map_kernel_range()` and `unmap_kernel_range()`, but they are not exported to the external kernel module.

So is there any other kernel API to do this kind of mapping?